# Using hyperlink to show only certain table rows

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make it so that only certain table rows get shown when a checkbox is checked.

I have been looking for a few hours now on how to make it so if I check "Mannen" it will only show the men in the table and hide the rest. In the case of "Allen" where I want it to show everyone when checked.

Question 1: How do I inline block the checkboxes and text instead of it being under eachother? I have tried doing it through CSS but not getting it to work. ( It seems for JSfiddle it works and its inline but on my local server this is not the case)

Question 2: I have been trying to get it to work with this JS code but I am a beginner so not sure if this is the correct way as I tried it and it does not do anything when I check a box.

JS Code

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    var targetClass = $(this).data('target-class');
    var $rows = $('tr.' + targetClass);
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $rows.show();
    } else {
        $rows.hide();
    }
});
```

HTML CODE

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
    <script src="Geslachten.js" defer></script>
    <title>Geslachten</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="javascript.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Checkboxes">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" data-target-class="mannen" value=""> Mannen
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" data-target-class="Vrouwen" value=""> Vrouwen
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" data-target-class="Allen" value=""> Allen
    </label>
  </div>

    <table >
        <tr>
          <th>Voornaam</th>
          <th>Familienaam</th>
          <th>Geslacht</th>
          <th>Foto</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Mannen Allen">
          <td>Noah</td>
          <td>Smith</td>
          <td><img src="man.png" alt=""</img></td>
          <td><img src="man1.jpg" alt=""</img></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Vrouwen Allen">
          <td>Emma</td>
          <td>Johnson</td>
          <td><img src="vrouw.png" alt=""</img></td>
          <td><img src="vrouw1.jpg" alt=""</img></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Vrouwen Allen">
            <td>Sophia</td>
            <td>Wilson</td>
            <td><img src="vrouw.png" alt=""</img></td>
            <td><img src="vrouw2.jpg" alt=""</img></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="Mannen Allen">
            <td>Mason</td>
            <td>Jones</td>
            <td><img src="man.png" alt=""</img></td>
            <td><img src="man2.jpg" alt=""</img></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="Mannen Allen">
            <td>William</td>
            <td>Davis</td>
            <td><img src="man.png" alt=""</img></td>
            <td><img src="man3.jpg" alt=""</img></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="Mannen Allen">
            <td>Liam</td>
            <td>Williams</td>
            <td><img src="man.png" alt=""</img></td>
            <td><img src="man4.jpg" alt=""</img></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="Vrouwen Allen">
            <td>Olivia</td>
            <td>Miller</td>
            <td><img src="vrouw.png" alt=""</img></td>
            <td><img src="vrouw3.jpg" alt=""</img></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="Mannen Allen">
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Brown</td>
            <td><img src="man.png" alt=""</img></td>
            <td><img src="man5.jpg" alt=""</img></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="Vrouwen Allen">
            <td>Ava</td>
            <td>Moore</td>
            <td><img src="vrouw.png" alt=""</img></td>
            <td><img src="vrouw4.jpg" alt=""</img></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="Vrouwen Allen">
            <td>Isabella</td>
            <td>Taylor</td>
            <td><img src="vrouw.png" alt=""</img></td>
            <td><img src="vrouw5.jpg" alt=""</img></td>
          </tr>
      </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Jsfiddle link --> https://jsfiddle.net/uvhwy32q/

Comment: You first need to correct a few errors: `<img>` uses no closing tag `</img>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer uses a CSS only solution. However, this will require you to change the original HTML somewhat:

- make your `table` a child of `<div class="Checkboxes"`
- place the `<input>` elements outside the `<label>` elements

This way `<input>` and `<table>` become direct neighbours (siblings) inside `.Checkboxes`

- rename `.Checkboxes` to something like `.gender-select` as it has now also `<table>` as child. This is not required, but makes more sense.

Now you can use the `~` sibling selector in CSS to select specific elements (mannen/vrouwen/allen) when your checkboxes are `:checked`.

Generic CSS:

`.sibling-selector { display: none }
 [attribute-selector]:checked ~ table .sibling-selector { display: table-row }`

Where class `.allen` actually becomes redundant, but may be used for other purposes.

FYI

- it is common practice to use all lowercase `.classnames`
- `<img>` does not have an `</img>` end tag, which are errors in your code.
- checkboxes are `inline-block` by default

Check out the snippet

```css
.vrouwen, .mannen { display: none }

[data-target-class="allen"  ]:checked ~ table .vrouwen,
[data-target-class="allen"  ]:checked ~ table .mannen,
[data-target-class="vrouwen"]:checked ~ table .vrouwen,
[data-target-class="mannen" ]:checked ~ table .mannen { display: table-row }
```

```html
    <div class="gender-select">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">Mannen </label> <input type="checkbox" data-target-class="mannen" >
        <label class="checkbox-inline">Vrouwen</label> <input type="checkbox" data-target-class="vrouwen">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">Allen  </label> <input type="checkbox" data-target-class="allen"  >

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Voornaam</th>
                <th>Familienaam</th>
                <th>Geslacht</th>
                <th>Foto</th>
            </tr>

            <tr class="mannen allen">
                <td>Noah</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td><img src="man.png" alt=""></td>
                <td><img src="man1.jpg" alt=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="vrouwen allen">
                <td>Emma</td>
                <td>Johnson</td>
                <td><img src="vrouw.png" alt=""></td>
                <td><img src="vrouw1.jpg" alt=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="vrouwen allen">
                <td>Sophia</td>
                <td>Wilson</td>
                <td><img src="vrouw.png" alt=""></td>
                <td><img src="vrouw2.jpg" alt=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="mannen allen">
                <td>Mason</td>
                <td>Jones</td>
                <td><img src="man.png" alt=""></td>
                <td><img src="man2.jpg" alt=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="mannen allen">
                <td>William</td>
                <td>Davis</td>
                <td><img src="man.png" alt=""></td>
                <td><img src="man3.jpg" alt=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="mannen allen">
                <td>Liam</td>
                <td>Williams</td>
                <td><img src="man.png" alt=""></td>
                <td><img src="man4.jpg" alt=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="vrouwen allen">
                <td>Olivia</td>
                <td>Miller</td>
                <td><img src="vrouw.png" alt=""></td>
                <td><img src="vrouw3.jpg" alt=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="mannen allen">
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Brown</td>
                <td><img src="man.png" alt=""></td>
                <td><img src="man5.jpg" alt=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="vrouwen allen">
                <td>Ava</td>
                <td>Moore</td>
                <td><img src="vrouw.png" alt=""></td>
                <td><img src="vrouw4.jpg" alt=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="vrouwen allen">
                <td>Isabella</td>
                <td>Taylor</td>
                <td><img src="vrouw.png" alt=""></td>
                <td><img src="vrouw5.jpg" alt=""></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake with the IMG ending and also thank you very much for your help and tips. It now works which is already very good but I would still need to figure out a way to make it work through using Javascript instead of css. I feel like with your help I received this should be rather easy!

Comment: If this is what you need, accept the answer. Happy selecting male/female!